# How do you convert a firebase snapshot of observeDataEventType.value to observeSingleEvent?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, snapshot

**What I tried**:

I changed the following:

```
 refArtists = Database.database().reference().child("people");
    
    refArtists.observe(DataEventType.value,  with: { [weak self]snapshot in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        
        if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
            
            self.people.removeAll()
                            
            for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
```

to

```
    refArtists = Database.database().reference().child("people");
    
    refArtists.observeSingleEvent(of: .value,  with: { [weak self]snapshot in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        
        if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
            
            self.people.removeAll()               
            
            for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
```

Additionally, I tried it w/o weak self and the guard. I also added:         `Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true //Swift` None of these produced data in the cell(images and text) that the DataEvent did.

**What do the console warnings tell me?**

No error warnings in the console.

**What do prints tell me?**

peoplekey still prints out, but soon after the if prints don't happen.

**How does the fuller snapshot look?**

```
let thisUsersUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid //Mr. Dunn's uid

refArtists = Database.database().reference().child("people");

refArtists.observeSingleEvent(of: .value,  with: { [weak self]snapshot in


if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
    
    self.people.removeAll()
    
    for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        
        if people.key != thisUsersUid {
            print("peoplekey",people.key)
            
            let peopleObject = people.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let peopleEducation = peopleObject?["Education"] as? String
            ...
            let userId = people.key
            
            ...
            
            if Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date) {
                let distance = locCoord.distance(from: self.dict)
                print(distance, "distancexy")
                
                if distance/1609.344 < 3000 && self.array1.contains(people.key){
                    print(self.array1, "f111111")
                    
                    print("fee", self.dict )
                    print(distance, "distancexy")
                    
                    let peopl = Userx(Education: peopleEducation, .......)
                    
                    self.people.append(peopl)
                    let d = people.key
                    self.printPersonInfo(uid:d)
                    
                } else {
                    print ("w")
                }
            } else {
                print ("alpha")
            }
        }

        print("aaaaaaaa", self.people.map {$0.distance})
    }
    self.people.sort { ($0.distance ?? 0) < ($1.distance ?? 0) }
}
})
```

Note: I am adding the following after the initial question. This is where the problem with the single event seems to be (using self.array1).

```
    guard let myUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

            refArtists = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(myUid).child("e2")
            
            refArtists.observeSingleEvent(of:.value,  with: {snapshot in
                
               let myDomain = snapshot.value as? String
                self.bSnap = myDomain
                print("haaal", self.bSnap)

                
                
                               let peopleRef = Database.database().reference().child("people")
                               let thisPersonRef = peopleRef.child(myUid).child("e2")
                               thisPersonRef.observeSingleEvent(of:.value,  with: {snapshot in
                                   
                                       if snapshot.exists() {

            

                let query = Database.database().reference().child("people").queryOrdered(byChild: "e2").queryEqual(toValue: self.bSnap)
              query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                  var allUsers = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                  ///////end (1) of comment
                  if let index = allUsers.firstIndex(where: { $0.key == myUid } ) {
                      allUsers.remove(at: index) //remove the current user
                  } /////end (2) of comment
                    
                    for userSnap in allUsers {
                        let name = userSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "postID").value as? String
                        print(name, "NNN")

                    if let unwrappedName = name {
                        self.array1.append(unwrappedName)
                    }
                    }

                print(self.array1, "ahah")
                    
                  
                
                
                })
                                        
                                       } else {
                                print("no")
                                        
                                }
              })

          })
```

The other alternative, I guess, would be to keep DataEventType and to detach the listener somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function

```
someRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
```

reads the node `someRef` and returns its child data as a snapshot one time and one time only, not leaving an observer. Further changes will not fire an event (the code in the closure)

This

```
someRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
```

Adds an observer to the someRef node, retrieving its child data and leaving an observer on that node. Any future changes of any kind will cause an event and the code in the closure is passed a snapshot containing all of the child data.

Note that both functions are expecting a DataEventType so you can just shorten it to .value, .childAdded etc.

So in essence you don't need to 'convert' one to the other as they have different functions but return the same data - at least initially. .observe will continue to feed data back to the app as it's child data changes, and that may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks. The only weird thing about this is when I use the observeSingleEvent as in my original question, it does not even fire an event once - otherwise the data would appear on the table once. Then there would be no choice for me but to use the .observe. However, that can't be listening/observing continuously. It would hit firebase too often. I'd have to stop it after a few seconds. How would one do that? Or make it intermittently run every few minutes for a few seconds.

Comment: @uuuuuu I ran the two pieces of code in your question and they work exactly as described in my answer, every time. If yours is behaving differently, then there will be a difference in your code so further troubleshooting is needed. In your code, right after this function `refArtists.observeSingleEvent` and before this line within the closure `guard let self = self..` add this line `print("test test test")` so it's the first line in the closure and run your code. If that doesn't print then the `.observeSingleEvent` line isn't being called at all. Test your code and report back your findings.

Comment: Thanks. I tested it with print there and at every step along the way until the sort line. The prints all appear, so it runs, but there is something about using single event that prevents the data from displaying.

Comment: Update 2: I isolated where it doesn't print. It is in the  `if distance/1609.344 < 3000 && self.array1.contains(people.key){` bracket until the line after `self.printPersonInfo(uid:d)` That seems to indicate the problem lies in finding array1 with the singleEvent vs just observe. I'll add how I am getting array1 in the question.

Comment: yes, I tested it when removing array1 and it works then. So for some reason array1 works with the observe but not with the singleEvent. Very weird. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @uuuuuu Your added code is hard to read due to formatting but it doesn't appear there's anything wrong with the Firebase code. It's how the snapshot is handled that appears to be part of the issue. For example, the `var name` property which is actually a `postID` - `let name = userSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "postID")`. However, if you don't have any `postID`'s the entire process will silently fail `if let unwrappedName = name`. Also, if the query fails `queryEqual(toValue: self.bSnap)` the entire process will silently fail. Try `print(snapshot)` inside the closure and see if it prints.

Comment: hmm, the weird thing about that is it always works with .observe but never with Single Event. In the cases where this doesn't work (via Single Event), there are alway some members that satisfy `queryEqual(toValue: self.bSnap)` (but never all members). Similarly, there are always members with postID for `let name = userSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "postID"` and  `let unwrappedName = name`. I am thinking because .observe works, Single Event should too. But it doesn't

Comment: Something else I noticed that may help narrow down this problem. If I remove the `array1 if` requirement, the data loads immediately and always. However if I include the `array1 if` and use `.observe`, sometimes it does not load if the phone is stationery(ie on desk not moved). So something with `array1` is causing this to not work in `Single Event` and to sometimes only work it the phone is moved in `.observe`. That seems to suggest that something to do with `array 1`(the code I added yesterday) is only triggered if a change occurs, like a move.

Comment: I looked at the prints and it prints until `print(self.array1, "ahah)`, so it has to be simply that .observe recognizes self.array1 but Single Even doesn't. And observe only recognizes it if the phone moves. Weird